# Using FPDF, FPDF Easytable and FPDI togheter

Tags: fpdf, fpdi

Good morning.
I need to create a dynamic pdf that includes also tables.
For that I set up my project with FPDF, then I added EasyTable.
So my first working demo looks like that:

```
include 'FPDF/fpdf.php';
include 'FPDF/exfpdf.php';
include 'FPDF/easyTable.php';

$pdf=new exFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage(); 
.... something ...
$table=new easyTable($pdf, 3, 'border:1;font-size:12;');
... table content ...
$table->printRow();
$table->endTable(4);

$pdf->Output();
```

My problem is adding the Fpdi library to embed some pages from another PDF. I did it long time ago with an older version of Fpdi, but something big has changed.

Following the official guide https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI I modified the my script like that:

```
// --- NEW LINES---
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
require_once('FPDF/Fpdi/autoload.php');

include 'FPDF/fpdf.php';
include 'FPDF/exfpdf.php';
include 'FPDF/easyTable.php';

$pdf = new exFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage(); 
.... something ...
$table=new easyTable($pdf, 3, 'border:1;font-size:12;');
... table content ...
$table->printRow();
$table->endTable(4);

$pdf->Output();
```

As you can see, I'm still creating the $pdf object via exPDF (it worked with the old version), but I modified my **exfpdf.php** file changing the class declaration from

class exFPDF **extends FPDF** {...}

to

class exFPDF **extends setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi**{...}

because Pfdi extends FPDF itself.

This is the error I receive:

> Fatal error: Uncaught setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\CrossReference\CrossReferenceException: This PDF document probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI. (See https://www.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parser for more details) in /var/www/html/DEVELOP/testpdf/FPDF/Fpdi/PdfParser/CrossReference/CrossReference.php:257

I'm stuck!
Any brilliant idea?

**I'm using fpdf v1.8.6, fpdf-easytable v2.0 and fpdi v2.0**

Thanks!

**----SOLVED-----**
It was an issue with the pdf file I was trying to embed. I don't know why, but it works fine with other PDFs.

Bye!

Comment: The error message is described in this [FAQ](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/error-document-compression-technique-not-supported/#question-89).